# Crashpad not generating a crash report after qml is executed

Tags: c++, qt, qml, exceptionhandler, crashpad

I'm trying to integrate Crashpad with Qt, with some QML in my code.

Here the crash report is generated successfully without any issue.

```
CrashpadClient *client = initializeCrashpad();

if (!client) {
    std::cout << "Crash not processed";
}
    
QApplication a(argc, argv);

//Here it generates a crash report
//but I don't need it here
std::cout << 3 / 0;

QQuickView* view = new QQuickView;

view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("InteractiveComboBox.qml"));
view->show();
       
a.exec();
```

But If I do make a crash happen after initializing Qml, it's not able to generate a report.

```
CrashpadClient *client = initializeCrashpad();

if (!client) {
    std::cout << "Crash not processed";
}
    
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QQuickView* view = new QQuickView;

view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("InteractiveComboBox.qml"));
view->show();

//Here it doesn't generate a crash report
//and I need it here
std::cout << 3 / 0;
       
a.exec();
```

How do I make it generate a crash report after executing QML code?

**Update : For a workaround on this, I reinitialized crashpad after view->show()**

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `show()` function in main resets the UnhandledExceptionFilter. You can do something like this.

```
auto exceptionFilter = SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(NULL);
view->show();
SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(exceptionFilter);
```

In this example, we set the UnhandledExceptionFilter to NULL to get the pointer to previous UnhandledExceptionFilter. After calling the show() function we use this pointer to call SetUnhandledExceptionFilter() and this reset

Comment: I tried this but it did not work for me. The way around I got was re-initializing crashpad again